# How do I add two variables in the HH:MM:ss format in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, adobe

I am a beginner in working with Javascript within Adobe Acrobat. We are working within a PDF form that has calculated fields. We would like to add two fields together in the format of `HH:MM:ss`. Specifically, we would like to write code that adds 10 seconds to each subsequent field. For example, if we had a start time of `01:25:50` (row 1), we would like the subsequent columns to read:

| Time |
| --- |
| 01:25:50 |
| 01:26:00 |
| 01:26:10 |
| 01:26:20 |
| 01:26:30 |

We have tried adding the fields using something like:

```
var time = "01:00:10";

var interval = "00:00:10";

var final = time + interval

event.value = final
```

However, this only returns the two string values pasted together. Additionally, using the basic sum function within Adobe did not work. I believe we have an issue with the data type not reading as a time, but I am unsure how to solve this.

Thank you for any help!